# When click on to Add File in IE, a black dotted border appears

Tags: html, css

I am using "input type = file". The clickable area is whole td.

```
<td class="AttachOnMouseOutText" id="urlid" nowrap="nowrap" valign="top" onClick="return getURL();" return true;">
<input type="file" name="AttachLink"  style="position: absolute; outline:0; filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(style=0, opacity=0); opacity:0; width:70px; height:50px; cursor: hand; left:-25px;" title="Add File Attachment" onChange="getWeblink();">
<span>&nbsp;Add File</span>
</td>
```

When i click on Add File. it browses for the file and black square border appears around the side. It happens only in IE. On Chrome it works fine. 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the below to your CSS:

```
:active, :selected, :visited, :focus { 
    outline: none;
}
```

The above will 'blanket' apply to all elements, to specifically target your input, you can use:

```
input[type=file]:active, 
input[type=file]:selected, 
input[type=file]:visited, 
input[type=file]:focus { 
    outline: none;
}
```

Comment: and how should i call this css class in my input type? sorry html, css is not my area. this is the second time i am doing it.. :(

Comment: though the solution is appropriate, somehow it doesnt work for me :( i hope its not an IE issue..

Comment: @Vasu - try replacing `input[type=file]` with `td`